# Is a cone the only possible simple objects that can be created from a piece of circular thin plate with the greatest volume?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations

Given a piece of of circular plate with negligible thickness. We are allowed to cut the plate, use all or part of it and glue the edges to create a 3D object into which we can pour water (or any liquid).

Cutting the plate into infinitely many tiny pieces to create a bowl may be possible but it is not practical.

The solution that came into my mind is to create a cone by cutting the plate into two pieces of sectors. For a certain angle that can be found with differential calculus, one of the sectors produces a cone with the greatest volume.

## Question

Is the cone the only possible solution with the greatest volume? How to prove this problem? I have no idea. Calculus of variation may help? But what function do I have to find to be maximized?

## Edit

- In the first step I have two cones. The smaller one can be merged as follows by creating a hole in the bigger one.

[image]

- A piece of plate obtained by creating the hole above can also be used to create other cones.
- Etc...

Comment: This can be addressed by calculus of variations to find a solution of revolution. Use a model $z=f(r)$, express that the integral of the area is constant, and minimize the integral of the height. You could also try a power function $f(r)=r^\alpha$ and find the best $\alpha$ (if this is tractable).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Is symmetrical property about axis of revolution a requirement?

Comment: No, I didn't say that (though it is likely). The only requirements are that the surface will be open above and the border horizontal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes. You did not say it. Why do we start by assuming the solution is an object of revolution? Sorry.

Comment: To try and answer your question.